# Handling simultaneous users on SSO on the same client with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies, single-sign-on

I have a Single Sign On login mechanism. It shares the login authentication result using cookies to the calling asp.net app. But the problem is that, if you have two browser windows logging in two different users simultaneously the last logged-in user is reflected across. How do you overcome this? Any ideas? One way I think is by making the calling app to pass an ID as query string to the SSO which will save the auth result on a cookie by the name as the ID (that was passed) and later you can read the result from the cookie by that name (same as the id).
Thanks in advance!